# Cloudera Installation issue (scm_prepare_node.sh: Permission denied)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

When i am trying to installing cloudera hadoop i am getting below error while copying the files stage

`/tmp/scm_prepare_node.BggVxw3l 
bash: /tmp/scm_prepare_node.BggVxw3l/scm_prepare_node.sh: Permission denied`

Can anyone help to fix this issue.

P.S: tmp having 777 permissions `drwxrwxrwt.  41 root root 4096 May  9 14:59 tmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my /tmp was mounted. So i changed noexec permissions in /etc/fstab then restarted the machines. Now everything working fine